# how to get firstDayOfWeek in pyspark via reflect method

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the first day of week, trying to find out whether it's Monday or Sunday with the below code but I get the below error

```py
spark.sql("""Select
reflect("java.util.Calendar", "getFirstDayOfWeek") as test
""").show(20,False)
```

data type mismatch: cannot find a static method that matches the argument types in java.util.Calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass only static methods available in particular class to reflect function.
To achieve the required output we can define UDF by making use of python's datetime or call getInstance static method available in Calendar class and extract getFirstDayOfWeek using regex.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

spark.sql("select reflect('java.util.Calendar', 'getInstance') as calendar") \
    .withColumn("firstDayOfWeek", regexp_extract("calendar", ".*firstDayOfWeek=(\\d+).*", 1)) \
    .show()  

+--------------------+--------------+
|            calendar|firstDayOfWeek|
+--------------------+--------------+
|java.util.Gregori...|             1|
+--------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't expect to get an answer on this so really appreciate it!

Comment: I also need to get the WEEK_OF_MONTH  from a timestamp column in the data is there a way to do this with the above method?

Comment: I could post this as a new question but something along the lines of Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)

Comment: I tried date_format('date_col', 'W') but this uses simpledateFormat and the locale defaults to US where Sunday is the first day of the week instead of UK/Monday and there doesn't seem to be a way to change this

Comment: But I can see that the Calendar method is correctly defaulting to 1/Monday as it takes my locale into account

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31879 some of info I've found on this issue

Comment: To get weekOfMonth, just changing regex should work- spark.sql("select reflect('java.util.Calendar', 'getInstance') as calendar") .withColumn("weekOfMonth", regexp_extract("calendar", ".*WEEK_OF_MONTH=(\\d+).*", 1))   .show(truncate=False)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in this case now I have a column with dates and need to extract the week of month from each of those dates into a new column

Comment: Did you try with UDF using python utilities?